# file.value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, file

I need to get the path of a file that I select in the JavaScript. What I researched, the `file.value` parameter should return this path. But it is returning `undefined`.

How to solve?

Below part of the code:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput'); 
var file = fileInput.files[0]; 
var path = file.value; 
document.getElementById("path").value = path; // ---> IT IS SHOWING "undefined"
```

Comment: What made you think that `File` objects have a `value` property? A question liked this could be asked for any non-existing property. `file.abcdefg` returns `undefined` as well.

Comment: I don't want to reveal my file paths to the web. It's a disclosure of personal information and isn't required for the browser to interact with the file system. I'd avoid browsers that (pointlessly) leak this information.

Answer (score 1):

`fileInput.files[0]` is a `File` object. It doesn't have a `value` property.

See: [JavaScript File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Also, for security reasons you can't get the full path of a file, just the filename.